# Android API 28 and Roboelectric 4.0-alpha-3 throwing Realm lib error

Tags: android, realm, android-testing, robolectric, android-9.0-pie

On switching the project to API 28 (compileSdk and targetSdk) Robolectric warned that it does not support API 28. On then updating the Robolectric dependency from v3.6.1 to:

```
testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:4.0-alpha-3"
```

Running tests then produces this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /var/folders/_3/zzf_y_vx2rnc685ysjf1hqr40000gn/T/robolectric-Method_testUniqueIDTest2854201631190706128/blah.com.blahapp-dataDir/app_lib/librealm-jni.dylib.5.5.0
```

I have tried setting this on unit tests, but it does not resolve the error:

```
@Config(sdk = [Build.VERSION_CODES.O])
```

The Application subclass does include a Realm.init() call in onCreate() which I suspect is a cause, but why is it occurring with Robolectric 4.0 when it did not with 3.6.1 and how can I resolve it?

Comment: I've tried 4.0-beta-1 and see the same issue.